# Django 1.8 Use field from "parent" model in "child" Foreign Key lookup

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-1.8

I want to use a field from the "*parent*" model in it's "*child*" Foreign Key.  Here are my 3 models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    bankno = models.IntegerField(db_column='BankNo',null=False)
    questionno = models.IntegerField(db_column='QuestionNo',null=False)
    question = models.CharField(db_column='Question', max_length=300)

class Questionaire(models.Model):
    bankno = models.IntegerField(db_column='BankNo')

class Response(models.Model):
    questionaire= models.ForeignKey(Questionaire)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    response = models.TextField(db_column='Response', blank=True, null=True)
```

I tried using this in the Response class:

```
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, Questionaire__bankno)
```

but I get

> "Undefined name 'Questionaire__bankno'"

I tried:

```
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, Questionaire.bankno) - and
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, Questionaire.objects.bankno)
```

and I get

> "AttributeError: type object 'Questionaire' has no attribute 'bankno'"

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: you already have a foreign key to Question in your Response class.    what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey, I have multiple questionnaires depending on the question bank selected.   if the user selects bank 1, i want the questionnaire to show those questions, etc for 2, 3, 4.  I figured the easiest way to do it was with the Foreign Key.  If you can think of another way to do it, I'm all ears.  cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add a many-to-many relation in Questionaire to Questions.

```
class Questionaire(models.Model):
    bankno = models.IntegerField(db_column='BankNo')
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Questions)
```

By this relation you will get all questions in a particular bankno.

Comment: OK, I'm confused on that one.  When the user goes in, the questionnaire will open (they enter their personal info) and then choose the question bank.  (1-20).  There is a one-to-many relationship between the Questionnaire (id) and Response (1 record for each Question (50 questions)).  I only want the question to change when they change the BankNo.  Maybe the best way to do it is move the BankNo to the Response Model and add an AdminAction to change Banks....hmmm